# email div content in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is it possible to take the content that is under a specific `<div>` and email that content?

For example:
If I have something like this:

```
<div id="1">
<ul>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
<ul>
</div>
```

Basically I want to just reference `<div>` and take the whole content and email it. 
is there any way to cache the contents in the div?
Is this anyway possible? ( javascript? php?)

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done on server side.

Comment: You might have just done this for the example, but the first character of ID shouldn't be a number. As per the W3C spec, it should be in [a-zA-Z]. This could potentially lead to issues with some of the solutions below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what further requirements you have. You could have a jQuery script send the contents to a PHP script, which then emails them out:

```
$.post("email.php", { data : $("div#1").html() }, function(result){
  /* handle results */
});
```

And then your email.php script looks similar to the following (**Don't use the following code as-is**):

```
<?php

  $to = "john@doe.com";
  $subject = "HTML Data";
  $message = $_POST["data"];
  $headers = "From: The Server <server@doe.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Will this also email the content of an iframe inside the div ?

Comment: @GovindKailas This will not email the content *inside* a nested `iframe`. If you wanted to do that, you would encounter a few other potential obstacles, related to the domain of the iframe source, and more.

Comment: iframe content is from the same domain, what would be the other obstacles ?

Comment: @GovindKailas You will need to grab the markup from the `contentDocument` of the `iframe` and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look into that, probably I would replace the content of iframe with a div and see if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, jQuery is probably the easiest way for you. You can add jQuery to your page with the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also reference your  content by using just $('#1').html(), or whatever the ID of your div is (in your example, it's 1).