# ob_start /ob_get_clean to Email html php content/results 

Tags: php, html, email, ob-start

I'm sure there are other better methods that I'm unaware of- just trying to take the simplest approach. Will post additional code as needed:

Selection php results from previous page:

```
                <div id="stage1sat" class="stageBox">
    <h3>STAGE 1</h3>
    <table>
    <?php

    ob_start();
    if ( ! empty($_POST['id']))
    { foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) { $_POST['id'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$key]); } 
    $in = implode(', ', $_POST['id']); 
    $sqlSAT1 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 1' AND id IN ($in) ORDER BY FIELD(id, $in)"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sqlSAT1) or die('MySQL Error ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error()); 
    }
    if ( ! isset($result))
    {
    echo 'You did not select anything';
    }
    else
    {


    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['timeShow'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bandName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    }

    ?>
    </table> 
    </div>
```

EmailProcess.php

```
      <?php

    $to = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "FPSF SCHEDULE";
    $message = ob_get_clean();
    $headers = "From: The Server <server@doe.com>" . "\r\n" .
               "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  ?>
```

Comment: `$message = $_POST['forminput']`?? What's the issue

Comment: It's a doozy of a 'form' - here's the code for one section of results-including 'selection.php' and 'process.php'  http://pastebin.com/k5Vn8CM7

Comment: Not your typical email form to send comments, feedback etc.

Comment: I think my goal is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827767/email-div-content-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the result of those php files with `ob_start()` and `$message = ob_get_clean()`.

Or change those php to write result to a variable (instead of `echo`ing them).

Comment: I'm still here- looking into the ob_start solution. Thanks!

Comment: What are the results? Basically you need to `ob_start()` before first html tag or php code printing the data - if that div `stage1sat` should belong to message, then you need to move `ob_start` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your problem.. Even while reading through the comments. If you have access to the php ini file or the ability to Turn settings on turn output buffering on.

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to capture the content of a div (on the users' results page) and use an html form to email it to the user.